# Append string from between starting from end

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$str = http://captoons2.se7enmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/eden-apple.jpg
```

I am having string as the guid in wordpress i want to convert it into

```
$str = http://captoons2.se7enmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/eden-apple-180x68.jpg
```

Comment: Where is size come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php

$str = 'http://captoons2.se7enmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/eden-apple.jpg';
$names = pathInfo($str);
echo $names['dirname'].'/'.$names['filename'].'-'.'180x60'.'.'.$names['extension'];
//Prints => http://captoons2.se7enmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/eden-apple-180x60.jpg

?>
```

Here's a [demo](https://eval.in/158531)